# Получение текста с определенного символа и до точки

Tags: python

У меня есть некий текст `some text: wi13912.` и мне нужно получить текст с : и до .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте срезы. Для поиска индексов среза используйте метод поиска подстроки в строке

```py
a = 'some text: wi13912. something else'
print(a[a.find(':')+1 : a.find('.')])
```

Результат:

```
 wi13912
```

Comment: Можно и так: `x.split(':', 1)[1].split('.')[0]`, хотя тоже с багами. Вот вы проверяли свой код на *какой-то текст. вот и ещё: текста немножко.*?

Comment: @0andriy от первого вхождения `:` до первого вхождения `.`

Comment: Правильно, первое вхождение точки может быть *раньше*.

Answer (score -1):

Через регулярные выражения можно попробовать, если строку для вывода можно как-то в него зашить.

```
import re

a = 'some text: wi13912. something else :yu12345 . something else'

result = re.findall(r'\w{2}\d{5}', a)
print(result)
```

вывод:

```
# ['wi13912', 'yu12345']
```

Comment: Старая шутка: *У вас есть проблема. Вы воспользовались регулярными выражениями. Теперь у вас **две** проблемы*.

Comment: @0andriy Ну, не без этого.